# Logging into a website to scrape data in java

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, httpclient, jsoup

I'm trying to log into the following website: http://www.deeproute.com. The login form fields are as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cookieexists" value="false">
<input size=12 type=name name=name>
<input size=12 type=password name=password>
<input type=submit name=subbera value="Login">
```

Here is my code in which I attempt to log in with HttpClient and parse the resulting html with Jsoup. Unfortunately, this returns the original html of the page in the same un-logged-in state.

```
        HttpResponse res = null;
        Document homePage = null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.deeproute.com");
        String html = null;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookieexists", "false"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            res = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (res != null) {

            try {
                html = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity());
                homePage = Jsoup.parse(html);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution with jSoup only code.

- Step 1. Get login form
- Step 2. Post form with cookies attached and all parameters.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp")
            .data("cookieexists", "false")
            .data("name", "username")
            .data("password", "pass")
            .data("subbera", "Login")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .post();

}
```